# Color the control group using geom_bar in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
a<-data.frame(Strain=rep(LETTERS[1:3], each=2),
              Mean=rnorm(6,0.5,0.1),
              Treat=rep(letters[1:2],6))
```

And I would like to plot it in a bar graph using ggplot, but having different fill colors for the strain corresponding to "C". I don't know if I have the proper approach, I simply add another layer with that particular code, but is says the length of the fill is not correct.

```
b <- ggplot(data=a, aes(x=factor(Strain), y=Mean, fill=factor(Treat))) + 
     geom_bar(position='dodge', stat='identity') +
     geom_bar(data=subset(a,a$Strain=="C"), fill=c('red','blue'),
              position='dodge', stat='identity')
```

Sorry for the basic question but so far I haven't been able to go around it. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
a$treat2 <- as.character(a$Treat)
a$treat2[a$Strain=="C"] <- paste("C",a$treat2[a$Strain=="C"],sep=".")

#function to create ggplot default colours
ggcolours <- function(n) force(hcl(h=seq(15, 375-360/n, length=n)%%360, c=100, l=65))

b <- ggplot(data=a, aes(x=Strain, y=Mean, group=Treat,fill=treat2)) + 
  geom_bar(position='dodge', stat='identity') +
  #use scale_fill_manual to specify the colours
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(ggcolours(2),"#FF0000","#0000FF"))

print(b)
```

[image]